# Lubuntu on old Samsung NC10 Netbook fails to boot: "Restoring Resolver State"

Tags: boot, lubuntu, ubuntu-netbook

I have downloaded the latest Lubuntu 14.04.5 ISO image on my Samsung NC10 netbook running an old Atom CPU with integrated Intel graphics today and try to boot it, but it keeps hangig at a acreen saying "*Restoring resolver state", and nothing else happens. So I guess it fails to initialize the graphics, because I can change to a console using Alt+F4.

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This misbehaviour does not appear in Lubuntu 16.04, so you should upgrade to that version.

Press ALT+F2 to get to the command line interface and type the following:

```
sudo-do-release-upgrade
```

You will be asked for your user name and password.

Before the release upgrade, I did the following, but I am not sure if it is really needed:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get upgrade  
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade  
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

And to restart the system:

```
sudo shutdown now -r
```

Comment: Thanks, I wonder why they do not offer an image of that version on the Lubuntu site, or am I missing something? It works after updating :)

Comment: Yes, I also wondered. It seems they have not updated their download area or whatever. The filename is *ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-i386.iso*, but what you get is the old version. Very strange.